# Can I use API to create a folder?

Tags: docusignapi

It appears that using the docusign portal, you can create your own folders in addition to the default folders that a user has.  I am wondering if there is a way to create one of these custom folders using the API.  There are APIs to move envelopes between folders, delete folders, get envelopes from folders, but I cant find one that lets me create a folder.  I am hoping it exists, and that i just am not finding it.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the answer is "no" for both REST and SOAP API's.

Answer (score 1):

No it not currently possible to programmatically create new account folders through the REST or SOAP API.

The closest you can do is to *move* envelopes from one folder to another, including moving envelopes into the recyclebin to delete them or void them if they are draft or in-process, respectively.  But there's no way to create a new folder through the APIs, you'll need to do that through the Web Console.